# Setting a time stamp in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

I struggle with setting timestamps in firestore.

Every time I come back to this, something seems to have changed in the firestore system so that what worked months ago, no longer works.

The [firestore documentation][1] says this should work:

```
createdAt: firestore.fieldValue.serverTimestamp()
  // createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

It doesn't.

When I try to use it, I get an error that says:

> 'ServerValue' is not defined  no-undef

When I try:

```
createdAt: firestore.fieldValue.serverTimestamp().toDate
```

I get an error that says:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'serverTimestamp' of
> undefined

I have asked questions about creating timestamps in firestore at least 20 times. I cannot find an answer that reflects what's in the documentation and remains consistently correct.

Does anyone know how to do it this week?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this works:

```
                createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
```

When I was using this (successfully) in around June 2020, I didn't need the firebase prefix. My firestore import is defined as

```
 export const firestore = firebase.firestore();
```

previously, it was sufficient to use firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(). This no longer works with firebase. I don't know why. Good luck to others struggling with these timestamps. If anyone knows why there is so much variation in what works and doesn't  from time to time, I'd love to understand.